# Pandas plot savefig, control frame size not using bbox_inches='tight'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

While plotting a dataframe:

```
d_f.plot()
plt.savefig(image.png, bbox_inches='tight')
```

`bbox_inches='tight'` can be used to drastically remove a lot of the frame (white space) in the final .png image.

Is is possible to reduce just a bit of the frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bbox_inches='tight'` or `plt.tight_layout` are both automatic.

You should use [plt.subplots_adjust()](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) instead:

```
ax = df[['y','w']].plot()
fig = ax.get_figure()
left  = 0.125  # the left side of the subplots of the figure
right = 0.9    # the right side of the subplots of the figure
bottom = 0.1   # the bottom of the subplots of the figure
top = 0.9      # the top of the subplots of the figure
wspace = 0.2   # the amount of width reserved for blank space between subplots
hspace = 0.2   # the amount of height reserved for white space between subplots
# These two can be called on 'fig' instead of 'plt' too
plt.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=bottom, right=right, top=top,
                wspace=wspace, hspace=hspace)
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

If you want to have no space on left, set `left=0`, if you want no space on right put `right=1`.

Here's an exaggerated example with no space on left and a lot on right with the facecolor set to red so we can see clearly:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=left, bottom=bottom, right=right, top=top,
            wspace=wspace, hspace=hspace)
plt.savefig('image.png', facecolor='red')
```

[image]